# How to get Top Selling product with quantity from access database and display on labels

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

I'm making a POS system. in that, I have to include the top 3 selling products with quantity on the dashboard which is I'm unable to figure out how to do it. please help me to do the coding and the data should retrieve form access database.

This is what I did to get the top 1 selling Item. I need to get top 2nd item and 3rd item also.
Any help

Image of the result expectation
[image: Image of the result expectation]

```
con = New OleDbConnection(cs)
        con.Open()
        Dim ct As String = "SELECT TOP 3 ProductName, Sum(Quantity) as Quantity FROM ProductSoldDB group by ProductName order by SUM(Quantity)"
        cmd = New OleDbCommand(ct, con)

        rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader()
        While rdr.Read
            lblProduct1Name.Text = rdr("ProductName")
            lblQTYProduct1.Text = rdr("Quantity")
        End While
        If Not rdr Is Nothing Then
            rdr.Close()
        End If

        con.Close()
```

Comment: Hello, if you've tried something and got an error or got output different from expected, please add more details. If you are expecting someone to give you a complete solution, I don't think you are going to get it.

Comment: This what I did to get the top 1 selling item. But now I want to get top 2nd and third also. how can I do it.

Comment: @judesuren you are selecting top 10 so why are you getting only one ?

Comment: yes i already corrected that mistake correct. even if I select top 3 how should I display it on separate lable.

like == top selling item1 = lbl1
      == top selling item quantity = lbl2

how should I do this?

Comment: Any help to do this coding?

Comment: wait for a minutes

Comment: @judesuren Check out answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Always_a_learner did the hard work of getting a working Select statment.

I do not like to hold a connection open while I update the user interface. So, I filled a `DataTable` and passed it to the `Button.Click` thereby separating data access code from the user interface.

Connections and commands need to be disposed in addition to closed so use `Using...End Using` blocks.

```
Private Function RetrieveData() As DataTable
    Dim sql = "SELECT TOP 10 ProductName, Sum(Quantity) as Quantity FROM ProductSoldDB Group By ProductName Order By SUM(Quantity)"
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    Using cn As New OleDbConnection("Your connection string"),
            cmd As New OleDbCommand(sql, cn)
        cn.Open()
        dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader)
    End Using
    Return dt
End Function
```

I created an array of Labels so we could loop through to fill from the `DataTable`. `i` is the index of the row, incremented by one on each iteration.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim dt = RetrieveData()
    Dim LabelsToFill = {Label1, Label2, Label3, Label4, Label5, Label6, Label7, Label8, Label9, Label10}
    Dim i As Integer
    For Each l As Label In LabelsToFill
        l.Text = $"{dt.Rows(i)("ProductName")} - {dt.Rows(i)("Quantity")}"
        i += 1
    Next
End Sub
```

To fill 2 different labels, one for the quantity and one for the name...

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Dim dt = RetrieveData()
    Dim QuanityLabels = {QLabel1, QLabel2, QLabel3, QLabel4, QLabel5, QLabel6, QLabel7, QLabel8, QLabel9, QLabel10}
    Dim NameLabels = {NLabel1, NLabel2, NLabel3, NLabel4, NLabel5, NLabel6, NLabel7, NLabel8, NLabel9, NLabel10}
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 0 To 9
        NameLabels(i).Text = dt.Rows(i)("ProductName").ToString
        QuanityLabels(i).Text = dt.Rows(i)("Quantity").ToString
    Next
End Sub
```

**EDIT**

Re: The $.  The $ indicates the beginning of an interpolated string which allows variables to be directly embedded if surrounded by braces { }. This became available in vb.net with Visual Studio 2015. In previous versions you can use String.Format for the same result.

```
l.Text = String.Format("{0} - {1})", dt.Rows(i)("ProductName"), dt.Rows(i)("Quantity"))
```

Comment: Good suggestion but user was not stuck in disposing connection . He has form interface related issue.

Comment: @mary This looks like a bit complicated to me. The reason is as per your coding "Button2", The top-selling product names are correctly retrieving from the database. but the Quantity of the product name not correct. Ex, as per my database **iPhone 11 pro** is the max sell product and its sold quantity is **9**. Your coding correctly showing the result of  **iPhone 11 Pro** as the max sold Item but quantity not correct.

Comment: Also your **Button1** coding getting an error by saying **Character is not valid.** highlighting `l.Text = $"{dt.Rows(i)("ProductName")} - {dt.Rows(i)("Quantity")}"` this row **"$"** sigh. Please help

Comment: this is what I updated for button 2
`Dim dt = RetrieveData()
        Dim QuanityLabels = {lblQTYProduct1, lblQTYProduct1, lblQTYProduct1}
        Dim NameLabels = {lblProduct1Name, lblProduct2Name, lblProduct3Name}
        Dim i As Integer
        For i = 0 To 2
            NameLabels(i).Text = dt.Rows(i)("ProductName").ToString
            QuanityLabels(i).Text = dt.Rows(i)("Quantity").ToString
        Next
    End Sub`
reason I don't want top 10 selling product. top 3 is enough for me. please revert back. thanks

Comment: @judesuren See the EDIT to my answer explaining the `$`.

Comment: Hi, @Mary Actually after do some clear understanding of your code it is actually working. but there is an issue with this coding. how about I have 2 products with the same sold quantities as Highest. then how should I display it. Any suggestions?

Comment: Acutally, the decision about what to display is between you and your client. I don't think it should matter if 2 have the same quantity. If they are 3rd and 4th, then one will be left out. Depending on how many you have your could display them all by just displaying them in a DataGridView. `DataGridView1.DataSource = dt` Just get rid of the Top 3 in the Select statement.

Comment: @Mary Thank you very much appreciate your response to my problem. It's solved.

Answer (score 1):

let's say you have 3 panel to show top 3 selling products and each panel have level in such way:
Panel 1 - label product name -  lblProduct1Name , label Quanity name -lblQTYProduct1

Panel 2 - label product name -  lblProduct2Name , label Quanity name -lblQTYProduct2

Panel 3 - label product name -  lblProduct3Name , label Quanity name -lblQTYProduct3

We would get lblProductName and lblQTYProduct in each iteration and set value for 
them.

Final code below:

```
    con = New OleDbConnection(cs)
    con.Open()
    Dim ct As String = "SELECT TOP 3 ProductName, Sum(Quantity) as Quantity FROM ProductSoldDB group by ProductName order by SUM(Quantity) Desc"
    cmd = New OleDbCommand(ct, con)

    rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader()
    Dim index As Integer = 1
    While rdr.Read

        Dim ctrlProduct As Control = Me.Controls.Find("lblProduct" + index.ToString() + "Name", True).FirstOrDefault()

        ctrlProduct.Text = rdr("ProductName")

        Dim ctrlQuantity As Control = Me.Controls.Find("lblQTYProduct" + index.ToString(), True).FirstOrDefault()

        ctrlQuantity.Text = rdr("Quantity").ToString()
        index = index + 1

    End While
    If Not rdr Is Nothing Then
        rdr.Close()
    End If

    con.Close()
```

Output Here- change look and feel according to your requirement :
[image]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214636/discussion-on-answer-by-always-a-learner-vb-net-how-to-get-top-selling-product).

Answer (score 0):

Here is the final code that solved my Problem with @mary 's help

```
Private Function RetrieveData() As DataTable
        Dim sql = "SELECT TOP 3 ProductName, Sum(Quantity) as Quantity FROM ProductSoldDB group by ProductName order by Sum(Quantity) DESC"
        Dim dt As New DataTable
        Using cn As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\User\Desktop\EME.accdb;Persist Security Info=False;"),
                cmd As New OleDbCommand(sql, cn)
            cn.Open()
            dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader)
        End Using
        Return dt
    End Function
```

```
Private Sub Load_TopSellingProducts()

        Dim dt = RetrieveData()
        Dim QuanityLabels = {lblQTYProduct1, lblQTYProduct2, lblQTYProduct3}
        Dim NameLabels = {lblProductName1, lblProductName2, lblProductName3}
        Dim i As Integer
        For i = 0 To 2
            NameLabels(i).Text = dt.Rows(i)("ProductName").ToString
            QuanityLabels(i).Text = dt.Rows(i)("Quantity").ToString
        Next
    End Sub
```

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Load_TopSellingProducts()
    End Sub
```

And Finally, I got the result as I expected

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i1X0E.jpg)